# App crashes after opening the splash screen in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

dHere is my splash screen Activity

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Icon = "@drawable/AppLogo", Theme = "@style/SplashTheme",
           MainLauncher = false,ScreenOrientation =ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class splashScreen : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(saveInstanceState);
            var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);           
        }

    }
```

hockey app unable to send the crash report for this issue
Here is the code for hockey app crash report,inside the MainActivity

```
protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            CrashManager.Register(this, "bfb3fc329eghsd21151d475886dd25058ef3f");
        }
```

This happens on few devices,Not all devices.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Register your crash reporter in the `OnCreate` of an `Android.App.Application` subclass.

#### Application Example:

```
#if DEBUG
    [Application(AllowBackup = false, Debuggable = true)]
#else
    [Application(AllowBackup = true, Debuggable = false)]
#endif
    public class App : Application
    {
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            CrashManager.Register(this, "~~~");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the mainactivity called sucessfully then it will report the crash,Application sub class will call after MainActivity LoadApplication(new App());

Comment: @VidhyaBhusan Android-based `Application`, not a Forms-based one. Re-read my answer: `Android.App.Application`

Comment: I am using Xamarin Forms,so I dont have any Android.App.Application sub class.So where I should call this CrashManager?

Comment: Add an Android application subclass to the project.